# Umbraco Document Type Field Default Value

Tags: umbraco

I would like set a default value for a date picker field in a Document Type in Umbraco.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily done using Events, on Document.New

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events

Just create a new class (eg. UmbracoEvents.cs)

```
using System;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
using Examine;

public class UmbracoEvents: ApplicationBase
{
  /// <summary>Constructor</summary>
  public UmbracoEvents()
  {
    Document.New += new Document.NewEventHandler(Document_New);
  }

  private void Document_New(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.NewEventArgs e)
  {
    if (sender.ContentType.Alias == "News")
    {
      sender.getProperty("date").Value = DateTime.Today; // Set the date for a new News item to today
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Compile it and put the assembly in the bin folder on your site

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Standard Values](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/standard-values-in-umbraco) or the [Default Values for Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/default-values-for-umbraco) package.

Comment: By the way, you'll get quicker and more answers if you ask them on our.umbraco.org instead of here.

Comment: I think these two packages is not helpful. For example in one of my content I have a date field. The user wants in content creating process for this document type, does not enter the date value and automatically date field is field by current date!

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved with sebastiaans first link. As it says on the page you just put in $date$ as the standard value. Then the package will insert current date when the user creates a document of this type.